# Capturing symbols and whitespace in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi folks I have a simple question (I think)

Using JavaScript, I want to be able to search for

```
"Grant B"
or
"Grant-B"
or
"Grant- B"
```

and have that match

```
"Grant-B"
"Grant  B"
"Grant?B"
```

Searching on the internet, I found this regular expression for matching symbols (on stackoverflow)

```
/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/
```

So my plan is basically first to find 1+ symbol or whitespace characters in the search string, replace them with the regex I used to find them, and then test that regex against the data. Currently, I'm struggling to get the first part (the match in the search string) working

The regex I am trying is

```
var regexStr = "[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/]|\\s";
try {
  var regex = new RegExp(regexStr,"i");
  var test = "Grant-B";
  var result = regex.exec(test);
  alert("result: " + result);  
}
catch (ex) {
  alert('error');
}
```

This is not matching correctly. Where have I gone wrong and what is the proper regular expression for what I am trying to achieve?

edit: Some I think have commented that this was not a clear question. I agree: I haven't been clear, and I was and maybe still am confused about what I am trying to do. So let me restate what it is I am trying to do:

The simplest way to say it is I want to match a search query of "Grant B" to "Grant B", ignoring all whitespace and symbols in the search string and in the test data. I'm struggling to figure out how to do this

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear to me... Do you rellay want to match "Grant B" or "Grant-B" or "Grant- B" ? Or is this an example? If it is an example, you shold should detail how to generalize it... Your example could be matched by `/Grant[- ]?B"/` ...

Comment: I agree with @MarcoS not clear either for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper regexp would be:

```
Grant[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\\\/\s]+B
```

You can try it here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iK1jY6/3)

If you want to allow "GrantB" as a solution, switch the + for a * at the end of the regexp.

Please also note that you might need to escape some characters depending on the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Grant([\-!$%\^&*()_+|~=`{}[\]:";'<>?,./\\]|\s)+B
```

Edit: In my mind the objective is to find the word "Grant" followed by the word "B" and accepting any mix of whitespaces and symbols caracters in between.

So

```
var patternWasFound = (/Grant([\-!$%\^&*()_+|~=`{}[\]:";'<>?,.\/\\]|\s)+B/i).test(strng);
```

or

```
var patternWasFound = (new RegExp("Grant"+ "([\\-!$%\\^&*()_+|~=`{}[\\]:";'<>?,./\\\\]|\\s)+" +"B" ), "i").test(strng);
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for all cases where there are one or more non-alphanumeric characters then `regex=/[^\w]+/` is a more concise way to do it. (the \w matches to any alphanumeric, [^\w] negates that and the + means one or more).  I think it was the + you were missing from your search above.

If you are wanting to match to 'Grant B' specifically then you could use `/Grant[^\w]+B/` .

The \w character includes underscores so if you want them included in your non-alpha search you will need `[^A-Za-z0-9]` in all cases above or go back to the long list of symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try this:

**Example 1**

`[\w]+[^w]*[\w]+`

*Breakdown of Example 1*

1. `\w` - Any word like Character (a-z, A-Z, _ and 0-9)
2. `+` - 1 or more times
3. `*` - Any number of times
4. `^` - When used inside a square bracket means "except"

**Example 2**

If you would like it to stick with only alphabetical characters

`([a-zA-Z]+[^\w]+[a-zA-Z]+)`

*Breakdown of Example 2*

1. `a-zA-Z` - Any letter, lower case or upper case

For the other usages in this example, see example 1